# Removing overlapping tuple values using Python

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a list of tuples (let's name it yz_list) that contains N tuples, which have the start and end values like: (start, end), represented by the example below:

```
yz_list = [(0, 6), (1, 7), (2, 8), (3, 9), (4, 10), (5, 11), (6, 12), (18, 24)]
```

And I would like to remove all values which are overlapped by the interval of a previous saved tuple. The output that represents this case on the sequences showed above is:

```
 result = [(0,6), (6,12), (18,24)]
```

How could I achieve this result using Python?

## Edit #1

The below code is the code that I'm generating this tuples:

```
for i, a in enumerate(seq):
    if seq[i:i+multiplier] == "x"*multiplier:
        to_replace.append((i, i+multiplier))

for i, j in enumerate(to_replace):
    print(i,j)
    if i == 0:
        def_to_replace.append(j)
    else:
        ind = def_to_replace[i-1]
        print(j[0]+1, "\n", ind)
        if j[0]+1 not in range(ind[0], ind[1]):
            def_to_replace.append(j)
    # print(i, j)
print(def_to_replace)
for item in def_to_replace:
    frag = replacer(frame_calc(seq[:item[0]]), rep0, rep1, rep2)
    for k, v in enumerate(seq_dup[item[0]:item[1]]):
        seq_dup[int(item[0]) + int(k)] = list(frag)[k]

return "".join(seq_dup)
```

As I'm developing with TDD, I'm making a step-by-step progress on the development and now I'm thinking on how to implement the removal of overlaping tuples. I don't really know if it's a good idea to use them as sets, and see the overlapping items.

The pseudocode for generating the result list is:

```
for item in yz_list:
    if is not yz_list first item:
        gets item first value
        see if the value is betwen any of the values from tuples added on the result list
```

Comment: How did you do that by hand?  What code do you have to carry out that process?  What's wrong with that code?  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Comment: Hey Prune, I did it by hand. I was trying to execute the code that now is available on the post (sorry for the mess).

Comment: What is the previously saved tuple you used to generate your output from your input? For instance why do the first two tuples split on the value 6?

Comment: @ViniciusMesel  Thanks for the update.  Down-vote and closure vote retracted.

Comment: When you get to a resolution, please remember to up-vote useful things and accept your favourite answer (even if you have to write it yourself), so Stack Overflow can properly archive the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may work. No fancy stuff, just manually process each tuple to see if either value is within the range of the saved tuple's set bounds:

```
yz_list = [(0, 6), (1, 7), (2, 8), (3, 9), (4, 10), (5, 11), (6, 12), (18, 24)]

result = [yz_list[0]]

bounds = yz_list[0][0], yz_list[0][1]

for tup in yz_list[1:]:
    if tup[0] in range(bounds[0], bounds[1]) or tup[1] in range(bounds[0], bounds[1]):
        pass
    else:
        result.append(tup)

print result # [(0, 6), (6, 12), (18, 24)]
```

Comment: If you append the tuple `(19, 23)` to `yz_list`, then the result is `[(0, 6), (6, 12), (18, 24), (19, 23)]`.  This is incorrect, because the `(19, 23)` is overlapped by `(18, 24)`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a class that calculates the overlaps using efficient binary search, and code showing its use to solve your problem.  Run with python3.

```
import bisect
import sys

class Overlap():

    def __init__(self):
        self._intervals = []

    def intervals(self):
        return self._intervals

    def put(self, interval):
        istart, iend = interval
        # Ignoring intervals that start after the window.                                       
        i = bisect.bisect_right(self._intervals, (iend, sys.maxsize))

        # Look at remaining intervals to find overlap.                                          
        for start, end in self._intervals[:i]:
            if end > istart:
                return False
        bisect.insort(self._intervals, interval)
        return True


yz_list = [(0, 6), (1, 7), (2, 8), (3, 9), (4, 10), (5, 11), (6, 12), (18, 24)]

ov = Overlap()
for i in yz_list:
    ov.put(i)

print('Original:', yz_list)
print('Result:', ov.intervals())
```

OUTPUT:

```
Original: [(0, 6), (1, 7), (2, 8), (3, 9), (4, 10), (5, 11), (6, 12), (18, 24)]                 
Result: [(0, 6), (6, 12), (18, 24)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
yz_list = [(0, 6), (1, 7), (2, 8), (3, 9), (4, 10), (5, 11), (6, 12), (18, 24)]

result = []
for start, stop in yz_list:
    for low, high in result:
        if (low < start < high) or (low < stop < high):
            break
    else:
        result.append((start, stop))
```

This gives the desired output, and it's pretty easy to see how it works.  The `else` clause basically just means "run this if we didn't `break` out of the loop".