# Remove overlapping spans from list of tuple values based on the length of spans in python

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list of tuples with character spans. But there are instances where there is an overlap of the spans.
My aim is to modify the tuple list in such a way that for overlaps only the larger span values is kept and smaller span deleted

Example:

```
Original list: [(2, 3), (7, 9), (10, 11), (10, 12), (15, 17), (16, 17), (20, 21), (20, 29), (21, 28)]
Modified list: [(2, 3), (7, 9), (10, 12), (15, 17), (20, 29)]
```

Here (10,11) , (16,17) , (20,21) , (21,28) were removed as they had a bigger span overlap with (10,12) , (15,17) and (20,29) respectively.

I found some answers which deal with the overlap like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47425881) but these don't deal with the larger span thing.

My thought was to sort on length of the span difference in descending order and then search for overlaps somehow. This search for overlap is something I cannot figure out

Comment: One small confusion, here you say `(21,28)` should be removed for overlap with `(20,29)` , am I misunderstanding, or is that an error?

Comment: Yes, (21,28) lies inside (20,29) so should be removed

Comment: then, do you mind explaining it a little more so I can help? I think I misunderstood your initial question

Comment: Okay, so basically consider a number line wherein you have a line from 20 to 29 and then another line from 21 to 28. Now, 21 > 20 and 28 < 29 and if you visualise it on numberline then (21,28) line would completely be inside (20,29) line. In these cases, I want the bigger line i.e. (20,29) to be taken.
Does this help?

Comment: Ahhh, yes. That does make sense now, Let me think about the code and I will update it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Code**

```
values = [(2, 3), (7, 9), (10, 11), (10, 12), (15, 17), (16, 17), (20, 21), (20, 29), (21, 28)]
outputs = []
for value in values:
    flag = True
    outputsLoop = outputs[:]
    for output in outputsLoop:
        fromVal, toVal = output
        if value[0] in range(fromVal,toVal+1) or value[1] in range(fromVal,toVal+1):
            if (value[1]-value[0]) > (toVal - fromVal):
                outputs.remove(output)
            else:
                flag = False
    if flag == True:
        outputs.append(value)
print(outputs)
```

**Output**

```
[(2, 3), (7, 9), (10, 12), (15, 17), (20, 29)]
```

**Code explanation**

The code loops through the values, and checks them for each part in the checked numbers, and keeps the value with the bigger span. It is not the most efficient or the cleanist code if I had to guess, but it works. And I do believe I can probably optimize it further when I have time.

Comment: Thanks for your reply :) But the outputs don't add up as since (15,17) exists so (16,17) which is an overlap and smaller gap than (15,17) should be removed. Same with (21,28)

Comment: Thanks Zaid! Can you please define the scope of optimization, i.e. if you can indicate what or how can this be optimized, I can also try from my end

Comment: @Alex for one, the code isn't the cleanest, and it can be shortened and made faster. I do think some standard functions in python could replace parts of this code, or some of the newer-released operators/list comprehension/lookups could be useful here